# Detect if Qualtrics tab is active except on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I am trying to keep a count of how many times a respondent leaves my Qualtrics survey while completing it—that is, how many times the tab the survey is on becomes inactive, blurred, or not visible. I have that working with this code in the header of the Qualtrics survey, where `leaveCount` is an embedded data object added to the top of the survey flow with a value of 0.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var count = "${e://Field/leaveCount}"
    $(window).blur(function(){
        count++
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('leaveCount', count);
    });
});

</script>
```

However, there is one page of the survey (with only 1 question on it, “QID3”) when they are asked to leave the survey momentarily, and I do not want that inactivity to be included in the count. In other words, I want it to count inactivity on every page except this one.

These are 2 of the things I have tried, but they don't work. Instead of not counting on the page with “QID3,” it doesn’t count at all any more.

```
// attempt with .equals()
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    String qid = Object.keys(Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.QuestionInfo)[0];
    var count = "${e://Field/leaveCount}"
    if (!”QID3".equals(qid)) {
        $(window).blur(function(){
            count++
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('leaveCount', count);
        });
    };
});

</script>


// attempt with !=
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    String qid = Object.keys(Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.QuestionInfo)[0];
    var count = "${e://Field/leaveCount}"
    if (Object.keys(Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.QuestionInfo)[0] != qid) {
        $(window).blur(function(){
            count++
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('leaveCount', count);
        });
    };
});

</script>
```

I'm not an everyday Javascript user, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your window blur function in the if, you want to put your if in the window blur. something like this *should* work, though I haven't tested it.

```
// attempt with .equals()
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  var qid = Object.keys(Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.QuestionInfo)[0];
  var count = "${e://Field/leaveCount}";
    $(window).blur(function(){
        if ( qid !== "QID3" ) {
          count++
          Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('leaveCount', count);
        };
    });
});

</script>
```

It's also worth mentioning, JavaScript is not strongly typed, so "string qid = ..." will not work. all variables in JavaScript are just variables.

Comment: Come to think of it, the problem may have JUST been the attempt to strongly type that string.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this didn't work for me. I get the same result as what I've tried so far: it doesn’t count at all any more, on any page in the survey.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but try the following. Basically, Anthony's idea, but just looks for the id QID3.

```
<script>
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  var count = "${e://Field/leaveCount}";
    $(window).blur(function(){
        if (!$('QID3')) {
          count++;
          Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('leaveCount', count);
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also gives same result as what I've tried so far: no counting at all on any page in the survey.